# What is fragment_main.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

On updating ADT a fragment_main.xml is created apart from activity_main.xml,what is the neccessity of fragment_main.xml ?
Is it neccesary to write the code in both xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most people are using `Fragments` these days, the new ADT update provides templates to avoid having to write all that code yourself. `fragment_main.xml` is the layout file that corresponds to the `Fragment` created by the template. You can avoid creating the `Fragment` if you click on `Blank Activity` on the new project wizard when creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely necessary, in the last update Google decided that the programmers need use more the Fragments
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm

This is because in this moment exists multiple devices with differents resolutions an screen sizes, and programing using just activitys is not a best practices, actually the fragments is the best way to programming for multiple devices.